# Why isn't this C code's \t working?

Tags: c, numbers, printf

I am trying to print a pattern of numbers. Try running this code with a input of 20, you will see that the tab spaces are all in the wrong place, they don't follow the order. I know that the tab spaces jump to the next header, but is there a way to avoid it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n, count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%dnumber\t", i);
        count++;
        if(count == 4)
        {
            count = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Is there a way to do this with tab spaces only(i.e., "\t" only) instead of using an ordinary white space.

Here is the output that I am getting.

[image]

But what I want is this

[image]

Comment: Please show the expected output, and the faulty output, in the question.

Comment: __tab spaces are all in the wrong place_  I do not know where the right place is.  _they don't follow the order_ - The order of the knights templar perhaps?

Comment: If you remove "number" from the print, they might look in "order"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but try `%2dnumber\t` instead of `%dnumber\t`

Comment: TAB goes to the next multiple of 8 columns. If the number is only 1 digit, you print something like `1number`. This takes up 7 columns, so TAB adds 1 space. But if the number is 2 digits, `10number` takes up 8 columns by itself, so TAB jumps to column 16.

Comment: @hashdefine The whole point of adding "number" was to force myself to learn about why tabspace wouldn't work.

Comment: @EdHeal I have updated my question.

Comment: Tab is not all that useful for presentation, it's more useful as a delimitor for data items in input. From the question update I suggest formatting each item with `sprintf` into a local string (of sufficient size) and then `printf` that string to output with a field width, for example `printf("%16s", strg);`

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes format field specifiers are standard, but what if I am trying to learn why tabs don't work? That was the sole reason why I posted this question.

Comment: @Riley Thanks. That really helped.

Comment: @lufork I edited previous comment. The `tab` just advances to the next "tab stop" like on a typewriter but does not consider the field width you actually want. Notice the oddity comes where you have a 2-digit number.

Comment: Look at the first oddity `10number`. At the end it is already at the next tabstop, so printing `\t` pushes it on to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    scanf( "%d", &n );

    for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%02dnumber\t", i );

        if( i % 4 == 0 )
            printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
16
01number    02number    03number    04number    
05number    06number    07number    08number    
09number    10number    11number    12number    
13number    14number    15number    16number
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

There are several different problems here.

But it sounds like your main question is "gee: the tabs don't line up like I expect."

SUGGESTED ALTERNATIVE:

Consider using "field length specifiers" in `printf()`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

EXAMPLE:

```
printf ("%-20s", mystring);  // Will always be exactly 20 characters
printf ("%06d", myint);  // 6-digits, zero filled
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was expecting an answer involving "\t" like someone else suggested.

Comment: Important point (as Weathervane said): `Tab is not all that useful for presentation`.  The tab spacing may or may appear as you expect.  Worse, the tab spacing will almost certainly *DIFFER* between a DOS cmd prmopt ... or an SSH window .. or notepad ... or a text editor ... or a SVN or Git ...

Comment: "Will always be exactly 20 characters"  --> Will always be at least 20 characters." as it is the "optional minimum field width".  Did you mean `"20.20s"?